# Flutter dart Gmaps Polygons "Integraty check"

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, polygon

i am new to flutter and i am trying to let users define zones in gmap by using marks to draw polygons.
[Example of a zone, with 3 markers/point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1RKA.png)

So, now what i want is to check if the user is not trying to do some like crossing the lines like this:
[Check for this not to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEs1s.png)

the numbers shown in the markers are not relavant, so i could do some math between coordinates and just redraw the polygon, but i wanted to avoid that just cause im lazy =)

and i noticed that when you cross the lines the polygon is not filled anymore, so it has some kind of internal check, that i would like to access if possible.

I am using Gmap and drawing the polygons with following code:

```
      ...
      Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};
      int lastMarkerID = 0;
      Set<Polygon> _polygons = HashSet<Polygon>();
      ...
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Add Zone')),
          body: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              GoogleMap(
                onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                initialCameraPosition: _kGoogleInitialCamera,
                onLongPress: (latlang) {
                  _addMarkerLongPressed(latlang);
                },
                markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
                polygons: _polygons,
                polylines: _polylines,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
      ...
  Future _addMarkerLongPressed(LatLng latlong, [_lastMarkerID]) async {
    _lastMarkerID ?? lastMarkerID++;
    _lastMarkerID = _lastMarkerID ?? lastMarkerID;
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(_lastMarkerID.toString());
    Marker marker = Marker(
      markerId: markerId,
      draggable: true,
      position: latlong,
      onDragEnd: ((value) {
        _addMarkerLongPressed(value, _lastMarkerID);
      }),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(
        title: markerId.value,
      ),
      consumeTapEvents: true,
      onTap: _showDialog(
          context, <String>["Delete Marker"], _lastMarkerID, _deleteMarker),
      icon: await createCustomMarkerBitmap(markerId.value),
    );

    markers[markerId] = marker;
    _setPolygons();
    setState(() {});
  }
  ...
   void _setPolygons() {
    _polygons.clear();
    List<LatLng> polygonLatLongs = List<LatLng>();
    markers.forEach((key, value) {
      Commons.log(value.position);
      polygonLatLongs.add(value.position);
    });
    if (polygonLatLongs.length >= 3) {
      _setPolylines(polygonLatLongs);
      polygonLatLongs.add(polygonLatLongs.first);
    }
    _polygons.add(
      Polygon(
        polygonId: PolygonId("0"),
        points: polygonLatLongs,
        fillColor: Commons.colorPolygonAddZone,
        strokeColor: Commons.colorPolygonStrokeAddZone,
        strokeWidth: Commons.strokeWidthPolygonAddZone,
      ),
    );
  }
```

As i said i'm new to this so feel free to sugeste other ways to achive this.

I could only find posts about check if a point is inside the polygon sorry if it's repeated question.